# Matlab plot - cannot convert double to a handle

Tags: matlab, plot

in the script I'm working with, I need to estimate the values of the function `f(xx, deg)` for different values of `xx` and `deg` (code below). When I run the code, I get the following error: `Cannot convert double value 202.893 to a handle`. I checked the [Matworks website](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/11/05/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-3-compatibility-considerations-in-the-new-graphics-system/#eed4c37f-5539-4ebb-b5e3-eb41e880b752) but the explanation is not very clear. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Here's the piece of code related to the problem:

```
g = figure; xlabel('Omega'); ylabel('Y');
plot(Angle, Y, '*'); hold on;
for xx = 1:number_centers
    for deg = 1:180
          f(xx, deg) = double((R_fit(xx)*sind(alpha_fit(xx)+deg)/0.05)+113);
    end
    plot(1:180, f(xx,:), '.');
end
```

Comment: Have you defined `f` before `f(xx, deg)`?

Comment: Because you haven't told us what all your variables are (class, size), we can't replicate the problem with what you've given us (but @Eypros is probably on the right track).  Try using `whos` on the command line (e.g. `whos f`).

Comment: Place a debug point, run the script line by line and tell us which line is generating the error. Also you may consider [preallocating](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html) your variable `f` before the loop: `f=zeros(number_centers,180);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem following @Epyros' suggestion: all I had to do was to define `f` before the two for loops. In this way, the final code is

```
g = figure; xlabel('Omega'); ylabel('Y');
    plot(Angle, Y, '*'); hold on;
    f = zeros(number_centers, 180);
    for xx = 1:number_centers
        for deg = 1:180
            f(xx, deg) = double((R_fit(xx)*sind(alpha_fit(xx)+deg)/0.05)+113);
        end
    plot(1:180, f(xx,:), '.');
    end
```

Comment: Preallocating is normally best practice, but note that for this to have been the solution, it is likely that `f` was previously used as a graphics handle.